# Multiple borrows of self with while loops and tokio channels

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, rust-tokio

I'm pretty new to Rust and have code similar to the following.

```rust
struct MyStruct {
    api_receiver: Option<Receiver<String>>
}

impl MyStruct { 
    fn process_response(&mut self, payload: String) {
        println!("*process_response");
    }

    pub fn event_pump(&mut self) {
        if let Some(rx) = &mut self.api_receiver {
            while let Ok(message) = rx.try_recv() {
                self.process_response("message".to_string());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have simplified it down for a simple explanation. I'm using Tokio and channels although I don't think that is relevant here.

The code below gives me the following compiler error

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src\adapter\adapter.rs:95:17
   |
93 |         if let Some(rx) = &mut self.api_receiver {
   |                           ---------------------- first mutable borrow occurs here
94 |             while let Ok(message) = rx.try_recv() {
   |                                     ------------- first borrow later used here
95 |                 self.process_response("message".to_string());
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
```

I'm obviously missing something here.  The interesting part is if I change the line `while let Ok(message) = rx.try_recv()` to `if let Ok(message) = rx.try_recv()` then everything compiles and works as expected.

What am I missing with regards to loops and borrows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really quite simple when there is a loop:

```rust
while let Ok(message) = rx.try_recv() {
    self.process_response("message".to_string());
}
```

what happens is:

- check if `rx.try_recv()` returns `Ok` and bind it
- if it is `Ok` run `self.process_response(...)`
- we are at the end of the loop so start again
- check if `rx.try_recv()` returns `Ok` and bind it
- if it is `Ok` run `self.process_response(...)`
- ...

This clearly mixes the calls to `rx.try_recv()` and `self.process_response(...)` which both borrow from `self` mutably but that's not allowed.

In the `if` case what happens is this:

- check if `rx.try_recv()` returns `Ok` and bind it
- if it is `Ok` run `self.process_response(...)`

No mixing of `rx.try_recv()` calls and `self.process_response(...)` so the borrow of `self` can be released after checking the condition, so there is no overlap of the borrows.

To suggest a solution we would need to know further specifics, but one workaround could be to remove the `Receiver` from `self` temporarily for example with [`Option::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take):

```rust
        pub fn event_pump(&mut self) {
            if let Some(mut rx) = self.api_receiver.take() {
                while let Ok(message) = rx.try_recv() {
                    self.process_response("message".to_string());
                }
                self.api_receiver = Some(rx);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ok, that's great and makes.  

So in a situation like this whats the common way of doing it? Or is it just a no no.  

I know I could inline the call to process_response but I would rather not do that as it will likely be a little complex.

Comment: It highly depends on your actual code, instead of the workaround I added to the question a solution employing interior mutability could also work, or splitting up `self` into distinct parts, it all depends on info I don't have.

Comment: ah crossed over.  Ok so emptying the Option would mean I'm not holding onto the &mut on self?  Just tried it and does work so thank you.  
Still trying to get my head around the borrow checker and problems like this are confusing me a bit at the moment.

Comment: Yes, `Option::take` removes the `Receiver` from the struct, so `rx` is not borrowed, but something owned. That in turn means that `self` can freely be borrowed.